# Laravel 5.1 form - 'files' => true

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, laravel-5.1

I use Laravel HTML to create form but I have problem, so in creating form I have:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'vocuhers','files' => 'true','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}

    @include('vouchers.form',['submitButtonText'=>'Click to Add New Vocuher'])

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

But when I see my HTML form in browser there is just:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8888/vouchers" accept-charset="UTF-8">
   <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="dfgdfgdfgdfgdf">
```

so where is

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

which allow me to upload files from form ?

Why I don't get this HTML output:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://bedbids.com/chats" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="dsfdfgdfgdfgdfg">
```

What is the problem here exactly ?

Comment: Are you looking on the right page though? Your `url` says `vocuhers` while your `action`  says `vouchers`.

Comment: I solve that, Thats not a problem here

Comment: my controller was a problem ... there instead vocuher.create i have voucher.index ... thanks for help

Answer (score 7):

Your syntax is wrong. The following works for me:

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => 'your_url', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true))}}
```

Comment: I also try to add 'class' to form and dont work: {{Form::open(array('url' => 'vouchers', 'class'=>'form-new', method' => 'post', 'files' => true))}}

Answer (score 2):

Change `url` with `route` as below.

```
{{!! Form::open(['route'=>'vocuhers','class'=>'your_class','files'=>true]) !!}}
```

Comment: no, simply can't add new elemnet into form tag ... I also remove IlluminateHTML , now I have just Laravel Collective

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'vocuhers','files' => 'true','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```

change It to

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'vocuhers','files' =>true,'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']) !!}
```

as *Markinson*  said

Answer (score 0):

Change it to like this:

```
{!! Form::attributes(['enctype'=>"multipart/form-data"])open(['url'=>'vocuhers']) !!}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).