# how to get fileupload details on default laravel controller of register

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5.6

I upload file from register form, but I didn't get details of `$_FILES` on register controller. I want `temp_name` and filename I will get name of the file only. register controller get values as array data.

Can you please help with this issue.

```
$pathoffile=$_FILES['boxfile1']['tmp_name'];
$filename=$_FILES['boxfile1']['name'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set form attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

In Laravel you can do this by `{{Form::open(array('url' => 'your_url', 'method' => 'post', 'files' => true))}}`

Reference: [Laravel 5.1 form - 'files' => true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344259/laravel-5-1-form-files-true)